# How to make a Grid in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to make a grid like this:

[image]

Not the wx.Grid. Does anyone know how to do this, and could provide an example?

This would be for a GridSizer or GridBagSizer to separate the widgets.

Comment: are you just wanting to _draw_ a grid, or create a grid of widgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the drawing context of the <s>frame</s> wxWindow subclass(frame/panel/etc...really any wxObject almost).

one way of doing it is this

```
import wx
class MyCustomFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT,self.OnPaint)
    def OnPaint(self,evt):
        self.dc = dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        p1 = [0,0]
        p2 = [500,0]
        for i in range(100):
            dc.DrawLine(p1[0],p1[1],p2[0],p2[1])
            p1 = [p1[0],p1[1]+5]
            p2 = [p2[0],p2[1]+5]
        p1=[0,0]
        p2 = [0,500]
        for i in range(100):
            dc.DrawLine(p1[0],p1[1],p2[0],p2[1])
            p1 = [p1[0]+5,p1[1]]
            p2 = [p2[0]+5,p2[1]]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = wx.App(redirect=False)
    f = MyCustomFrame(None,-1)
    #f.OnPaint(None) --- dont do this!!!
    f.Show()
    a.MainLDop()
```

you could speed it up by using drawlines instead

```
    def OnPaint(self,evt):
        self.dc = dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        verticle_lines = [(i*5,0,i*5,500) for i in range(100)]
        horizontal_lines = [(0,i*5,500,i*5) for i in range(100)]
        dc.DrawLineList(horizontal_lines+verticle_lines)
```

In Order to do what you want with the grid sizer you could do this

```
import  wx
class   MyCustomPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,id)
        self.sz =   wx.GridSizer(5,5,0,0)
        for i   in  range(25):
            self.sz.Add(wx.StaticText(self,-1,str(i)))
        self.SetSizer(self.sz)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT,self.OnPaint)
    def OnPaint(self,evt):
        self.dc =   dc  =   wx.PaintDC(self)
        w,h = self.sz.GetSize()
        nr = self.sz.GetRows()
        nc = self.sz.GetCols()
        cell_w = float(w)/nc
        cell_h = float(h)/nr
        hlines = [(0,i*cell_h,w,i*cell_h)for i in range(nr+1)]
        vlines = [(i*cell_w,0,i*cell_w,h)for i in range(nc+1)]
        self.dc.DrawLineList(hlines+vlines)

if  __name__    ==  "__main__":
    a   =   wx.App(redirect=False)
    f1 = wx.Frame(None,-1)
    f   =   MyCustomPanel(f1,-1)
    #f.OnPaint(None)
    f1.Show()
    a.MainLoop()
```

you could also accomplish this with styles like this

```
import  wx
class SimplePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,str_val):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,id,style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        self.sz = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sz.Add(wx.StaticText(self,-1,str_val),0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.SetSizer(self.sz)
class   MyCustomPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):

        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,id)
        self.sz =   wx.GridSizer(5,5,0,0)
        for i   in  range(25):
            self.sz.Add(SimplePanel(self,-1,str(i)),0,wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sz)

if  __name__    ==  "__main__":
    a   =   wx.App(redirect=False)
    f1 = wx.Frame(None,-1)
    f   =   MyCustomPanel(f1,-1)
    #f.OnPaint(None)
    f1.Show()
    a.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Oh nice, Do you know how to make it work with a GridSizer or GridBagSizer to seperate widgets? (such as buttons)

Comment: or How could I overlay this over a GridSizer?

Comment: use a panel instead of a  frame and give use SetMinSize((w,h)) to give it dimensions a sizer will recognize..  Oh I see what your asking... that would take a while to answer...

Comment: why dont you want to use the wx.gridlib.Grid ? Im pretty sure you can have variable sized cells...

Comment: there somethign like that is what you want